# Azure Enterprise application SAML SSO for additional access url in an existed web application

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

We're using Azure Enterprise application of azure AD that configured SAML SSO to access a web application that built in separate tenant.

If we want to add additional access url for mobile access,

like:
current url(for PC):

> http://example.net

addtional access(for Mobile):

> **http://example.net/mobile**

the below URL configured in SSO would be same, as above page share same authentication at backend.

```
Reply URL (Assertion Consumer Service URL)

Sign on URL

Logout Url (Optional)
```

However,

```
**Relay State (Optional)  is supposed to be different.**
```

Do we need to create new enterprise application for this mobile SSO?
or add new SAML SSO in the current enterprise application?

[image]